# JavaScript regular expression match amount

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to write a regular expression to match amounts. In my case, what I need is that either the amount should be a positive integer or if the decimal is used, it must be followed by one or two integers. So basically, the following are valid amounts:

- 34000
- 345.5
- 876.45

What I wrote was this: `/[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2}){0,1}/`

My thinking was that by using parenthesis like so: `(\.[0-9]{1,2})`, I would be able to bundle the whole "decimal plus one or two integers" part. But it isn't happening. Among other problems, this regex is allowing stuff like `245.` and `345.567` to slip through. :(

Help, please!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regular expression is good, but you need to match the beginning and end of the string. Otherwise, your regex can match only a portion of the string and still (correctly) return a match. To match the beginning of the string, use `^`, for the end, use `$`.

**Update**: as Avinash has noted, you can replace `{0,1}` with `?`. JS supports `\d` for digits, so the regex can be further simplified

Finally, since if are only testing against a regex, you can use a non-capturing group ( `(?:...)` instead of `(...)`), which offers [better performance](https://jsperf.com/regex-capture-vs-non-capture).

original:

```js
/[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2}){0,1}/.test('345.567')
```

Fixed, and faster ;)

```js
 /^\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?$/.test('345.567')
```

Comment: even more simpler `/^[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/.test('345.567')`

Comment: Who'd have thought! But why does it matter? Isn't the matched expression found in the string in my case, irrespective of whether it's the only thing or part of a larger string?

Comment: @AvinashRaj Thanks for that! I wonder why there isn't the PHP (Perl?) equivalent of `\d` in JS. Would have made life even simpler.

Comment: this regex won't match the part of a larger string.

Comment: @dotslash you could also use  `\d` instead of `[0-9]`  in js.

Comment: @AvinashRaj I'm not trying to match a substring, so it works for me. But I am surprised it doesn't work without the `^` and `$`. :O

Comment: @joemfb since you're doing validation, you don't need a capturing group. Just turn the capturing group to non-capturing group.

Comment: @dotslash without the anchors , `\d+(\.\d{1,2})?` regex matches `56` part in `56.` input , since we made the dot part as optional. So it finds a match on this input but when you use anchors , `^\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$` forces the regex engine to match an integer number or a decimal number because we defined `\d{1,2}` inside the optional group not `\d*`.